# How to keep the original value on a table after an override?

Tags: tables

I have a table that displays the qty. entered by the user when they uploaded their spreadsheet. We want to show the user the alternative price for other quantities, so if they originally entered 80 they could see that if they change it to 100 the price may be cheaper and they can get a better deal. The stakeholders want the original quantity entered by the user to remain visible somewhere, so if they click on one of the radio buttons and the qty field updates with that selection but let's say minutes later they change their mind and want to revert to the original quantity how can we show them that?

[image]

Comment: Have you asked your stakeholders why they believe your users can't remember how many units they want, and require the system to externalize that memory?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey uploading a spreadsheet implies a large number of orders, so the assumption that the user won't remember them all seems reasonable to me...

Comment: correct @EvilClosetMonkey, there is a potential for large amounts of data and the user needs to be aware of changes made, not to mention that there is a good chance that the user won't submit the data right away, but take hours and sometimes a day or two. Granted they still have their original spreadsheet but we need to inform the user of changes made to the quantity field.

Answer (score 1):

**You could display an icon indicating the value was edited.**  One example would be the pencil icon when comments have been edited on this and other Stack Exchange sites.

**Clicking on this icon would show and allow reversion to the previous value.**